# Get inserted DOMNode

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following jQuery code used to insert a new DOM element. `someHTML` in this case is just a HTML string.. like `<div>text</div>`.

```
$area.prepend(someHTML);
```

I'd like to get a reference to the node after it is inserted in the DOMTree, with properly set parentNode and what-not.

jQuery filter functions like .find() and .filter() won't work for my situation since both create new jQuery objects. I need the actual reference to the DOMNode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How about doing this the other way round, with [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo)?  Construct the DOM node with the jQuery constructor, then prepend it to your existing selection, then use [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get the underlying DOM node.

```
var node = $(someHTML).prependTo($area).get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a variable for it?

```
var $someHTML = $(someHTML);
$area.prepend($someHTML);
//now you can reference $someHTML elsewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work fine, but another option is to give the new `div` an `id` when you create it. Then it can be referenced the normal way anywhere after it's been added to the DOM:

`$('#someElement').prepend('<div id="something"></div>"');
$('#something').html('whatever');`